# "Value of type [Shelter] has not member 'name'"

Tags: json, swift, performselector

I am trying to parse an endpoint for some JSON in Swift and use the `name` member as a title of my cell. I have created a struct, which conforms to the data offered by the endpoint. However, when trying to use it as my cell name, I get the error `Value of type [Shelter] has not member 'name'`.

Some code snippets:

This is my defined structs:

Shelters.swift:

```
struct Shelters: Codable {
    var objects: [Shelter]
}
```

Shelter.swift:

```
struct Shelter: Codable {
    var name: String
    var shortdescription: String
    var lastedited: String
}
```

Finally, this is from my ViewController.

```
var shelters = [Shelter]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    performSelector(inBackground: #selector(backgroundProc), with: nil)
}

@objc func backgroundProc() {
    let shelterUrl = "https://192.168.1.10/api/shelters/?format=json"
    if let url = URL(string: shelterUrl) {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            parse(json: data)
        }
    }
}

//JSON Parser
func parse(json: Data) {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    if let jsonShelters = try? decoder.decode(Shelters.self, from: json) {
        shelters = jsonShelters.objects
    }
}
```

This is where the code fails:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return shelters.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Shelters", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = shelters.name[indexPath.row] //It fails right here. With the error: Value of type '[Shelter]' has no member 'name'
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Shelter"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Value of type [Shelter] has not member 'name'`

If you look closely on the error description, it's telling you that a variable of `Type`: `[Shelter]` does not have an attribute named `name`. In other words, `<#Obj#>.name` is a property of `Shelter` and NOT `[Shelter]`.

So you need to reference an object instead of an array on the failing line, using: `shelters[indexPath.row]`, and then you can access `shelters[indexPath.row].name`.

Your line should be:

`cell.textLabel?.text = shelters[indexPath.row].name`

Comment: How is your answer different than Gereon's answer?

Comment: @PGDev https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers

Comment: That actually made perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use 
    `cell.textLabel?.text = shelters[indexPath.row].name`